How explicit were the (putative) secret speeches by Xi Jinping to build up China's nuclear arsenal to match that of USA & Russia?
NYT journalist David Sanger says in an interview about his book that Xi Jinping gave secret speeches as soon as he came into power promising to build China's nuclear arsenal to match that of US & Russia.
But at least on other matters like counter-terrorism strategies Xi was more metaphoric than concrete in similarly leaked speeches. So, how explicit are these leaked/secret speeches (attributed to Xi) about the nuclear parity issue? Are there any exact quotes from these?
Note: I'm just asking if these alleged secret speeches about nuclear parity are as explicit as Sanger claims; there's not much about them that can found on a quick search, unlike Xi's speeches about terrorism/Xinjiang, from which there are some quoted excerpts. I'm not interested in a debate about their authenticity. Skeptics on that (authenticity) will be/remain skeptics. (Just saying this because I tried asking this on Politics SX and got a ton of comments that 'secret speeches are secret' and 'if they're leaked we don't know if they're authentic'.)

I'm guessing Sanger is talking about these https://www.ucsusa.org/sites/default/files/2024-04/xi-second-party-speech-12-05-2012.pdf but the word parity doesn't appear on a quick search in there. Although there are other ways to say that. OTOH those were printed by the PLA, so I'm not sure if they count as secret, but the lead page says in translation "Internal Materials, Handle with Care". Also, they're supposed to be 35+4 speeches, but that excerpt only has a few pages,.
